# PHP mail - wrong sender (from:)

Tags: php, email, cron

I have a file that is run via cron. The file sending email to users.

But have a problem, the problem is that when I open the file via browser PHP params for mail reading correct sender is set up correctly with what I have stated in From:

When the file is executed by cron, the sender ignored and coming Linux user name and host name as the sender.

```
$headers  = "";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit". "\n";
$headers .= "Date: ".date("r"). "\n"; 
$headers .= "To: ". $users. "\n";
$headers .= "From: Somthing <no-reply@mydomain.com>" . "\n";

mail($to, "Remainder 1", "Message body", $headers);
```

Cron settings is like that

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/cron.php
```

Comment: Probably because the cron is running via `root`.

Comment: Is it posible to run cron by user?

Comment: Yes, do `crontab -u user` and then `-l` (list) or `-e` (edit)

Comment: Is `Somthing` copy&paste from your config or did you change this for SO?

Answer (score 0):

If you use like this '`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/cron.php`' you will try to execute the script from a different location than running it from the browser.

And if you include scripts with relative paths they will 100% fail.

Use like this and give it a shot : '`cd /home/user/; /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/cron.php`' so you run the script from it's location.

Comment: Yes, tried with cd /path/ it does not work. Still Sender appear in message source.

Comment: @Alan Try using SMTP to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

I never recommend running PHP scripts with cron the way you do. 
The reason is that PHP will almost always be configured differently (with different php.ini-specific settings) than when it is run via Apache.

The way I recommend doing it is via wget. Step-by-step, you have to do this:

1. Upload `cron.php` in a folder of your website, or somewhere accessible on the same server, but in it's own folder. Let's call it `cron-jobs`
2. Make sure it works via Internet by accessing `http://www.yoursite.com/cron-jobs/cron.php`
3. If you're on Apache, create a `.htaccess` file with rules

   ```
   Order Deny, Allow
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Deny from all
   ```
4. Test again to make sure you're not getting any 500 errors related to htaccess rules. This rule ensures that nobody else can run that script, except for the server itself.
5. Now modify the cron task to run the script like this

   `wget -q http://www.yoursite.com/cron-jobs/cron.php`

And you should see the correct `From:` field now.

Comment: You're right, it works with wget. The reason I do not use wget is that if Apache cuts out the script will not run again. This solution is not safe if you have larger files and make major processes. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Usually it depends on what the script does, but normally Apache shouldn't cut the script. PHP might, which is why you should do `set_time_limit(0);` and `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in your PHP script if you know it's running long. So again, Apache does not stop your script under normal circumstances.